# Adding two dictionaries to list by array

Tags: python, arrays, json

This is my below code and I would like to add jsondict value to parsedData list

```
parsedData = []
userData = {}
jsondict=[{u'Name': u'BILL', u'ID': u'1028', u'CARS': [u'BMW', u'AUDI']}, 
         {u'Name ': u'TOM', u'ID': u'1029', u'CARS': [u'TOYOTA', u'FERRARI']}]
for distro in jsondict:
    userData['Name'] = distro['Name']
    userData['ID'] = distro['ID']
    userData['CARS1'] = distro['CARS'][0]
    userData['CARS2'] = distro['CARS'][1]
    parsedData.append(userData)
```

But from this code I am getting two times last dict which is not correct and expected output should be like this:

```
[{u'Name': u'BILL', u'ID': u'1028', u'CARS1': u'BMW',u'CARS2': u'AUDI'}, 
{u'Name ': u'TOM', u'ID': u'1029', u'CARS1': u'TOYOTA', u'CARS2':u'FERRARI'}]
```

Comment: What is the current output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing the same dict twice (`parsedData[0] is parsedData[1]` evaluates to true). To stop this from happening, just create the dict in the loop:

```
parsedData = []
jsondict=[{u'Name': u'BILL', u'ID': u'1028', u'CARS': [u'BMW', u'AUDI']}, 
         {u'Name ': u'TOM', u'ID': u'1029', u'CARS': [u'TOYOTA', u'FERRARI']}]
for distro in jsondict:
    userData = {}
    userData['Name'] = distro['Name']
    userData['ID'] = distro['ID']
    userData['CARS1'] = distro['CARS'][0]
    userData['CARS2'] = distro['CARS'][1]
    parsedData.append(userData)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use dictionary unpacking in Python3:

```
jsondict=[{u'Name': u'BILL', u'ID': u'1028', u'CARS': [u'BMW', u'AUDI']}, 
     {u'Name ': u'TOM', u'ID': u'1029', u'CARS': [u'TOYOTA', u'FERRARI']}]
final_listing = [{**{a:b for a, b in i.items() if a != 'CARS'}, **{'CARS{}'.format(i):a for i, a in enumerate(i['CARS'], start=1)}} for i in jsondict]
```

Output:

```
[{'Name': 'BILL', 'ID': '1028', 'CARS1': 'BMW', 'CARS2': 'AUDI'}, {'Name ': 'TOM', 'ID': '1029', 'CARS1': 'TOYOTA', 'CARS2': 'FERRARI'}]
```

Edit: Python2 solution:

```
last_data = [dict([(a, b) for a, b in i.items() if a != 'CARS']+[('CARS{}'.format(i), a) for i, a in enumerate(i['CARS'], start=1)]) for i in jsondict]
```

Output:

```
[{'Name': 'BILL', 'ID': '1028', 'CARS1': 'BMW', 'CARS2': 'AUDI'}, {'Name ': 'TOM', 'ID': '1029', 'CARS1': 'TOYOTA', 'CARS2': 'FERRARI'}]
```

Comment: @MegaIng Please see my recent edit. I added a solution for Python2.

Comment: @MegaIng "hard to read" and "good solution" don't go in the same sentence